# Android firebase - why does clicking star always remove one child value?

Tags: android, firebase

This is FreeboardPost.java

```
public class FreeboardPost
{
    public String imageUrl;
    public String uid;
    public String author;
    public String title;
    public String body;
    public int starCount = 0;


    public Map<String, Boolean> stars = new HashMap<>();

    public FreeboardPost()
    {
    }

    public FreeboardPost(String uid, String author, String title, String body, String imageUrl)
    {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.author = author;
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;

    }

    @Exclude
    public Map<String, Object> toMap()
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("image", imageUrl);
        result.put("uid", uid);
        result.put("author", author);
        result.put("title", title);
        result.put("body", body);
        result.put("starCount", starCount);
        result.put("stars", stars);

        return result;
    }

}
```

This is FreeboardPostViewHolder.java

```
public class FreeboardPostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView freeboardtitleView;
    public TextView freeboardauthorView;
    public ImageView freeboardstarView;
    public TextView freeboardnumStarsView;
    public TextView freeboardbodyView;
    public CircleImageView freeboardprofileView;

    public FreeboardPostViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);

        freeboardtitleView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.freeboard_post_title);
        freeboardauthorView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.freeboard_post_author);
        freeboardstarView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.freeboard_star);
        freeboardnumStarsView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.freeboard_post_num_stars);
        freeboardbodyView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.freeboard_post_body);
        freeboardprofileView = (CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.freeboard_post_author_photo);
    }

    public void bindToPost(FreeboardPost freeboardpost, View.OnClickListener starClickListener)
    {
        freeboardtitleView.setText(freeboardpost.title);
        freeboardauthorView.setText(freeboardpost.author);
        freeboardnumStarsView.setText(String.valueOf(freeboardpost.starCount));
        freeboardbodyView.setText(freeboardpost.body);
        freeboardstarView.setOnClickListener(starClickListener);
    }
}
```

and this is FreeboardPostListFragment.java

```
public abstract class FreeboardPostListFragment extends Fragment
{
    private static final String TAG = "FreeBoardPostListFragment";

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FreeboardPost, FreeboardPostViewHolder> mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;
    private LinearLayoutManager mManager;

    private DatabaseReference mPostReference;
    private ValueEventListener mPostListener;

    private String image;

    public FreeboardPostListFragment()
    {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.freeboard_fragment_all_posts, container, false);

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mRecycler = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.freeboard_messages_list);
        mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

        Query postsQuery = getQuery(mDatabase);

        mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FreeboardPost, FreeboardPostViewHolder>(FreeboardPost.class, R.layout.freeboard_item_post, FreeboardPostViewHolder.class, postsQuery)
        {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final FreeboardPostViewHolder viewHolder, final FreeboardPost model, final int position)
            {
                final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);

                final String postKey = postRef.getKey();

                mPostReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FreeboardPost").child(postKey);

                viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FreeBoardPostDetailActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(FreeBoardPostDetailActivity.EXTRA_POST_KEY, postKey);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                if(model.stars.containsKey(getUid()))
                {
                    viewHolder.freeboardstarView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_24);
                }
                else
                {
                    viewHolder.freeboardstarView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_toggle_star_outline_24);
                }

                viewHolder.bindToPost(model, new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View starView)
                    {
                        DatabaseReference globalPostRef = mDatabase.child("FreeboardPost").child(postRef.getKey());
                        DatabaseReference userPostRef = mDatabase.child("FreeboardUserPost").child(model.uid).child(postRef.getKey());

                        onStarClicked(globalPostRef);
                        onStarClicked(userPostRef);
                    } 
                });
            }
        };

        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    private void onStarClicked(DatabaseReference postRef)
    {
        postRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler()
        {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData)
            {
                FreeboardPost p = mutableData.getValue(FreeboardPost.class);

                if(p == null)
                {
                    return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                }

                if(p.stars.containsKey(getUid()))
                {
                    p.starCount = p.starCount - 1;
                    p.stars.remove(getUid());

                }
                else
                {
                    p.starCount = p.starCount + 1;
                    p.stars.put(getUid(), true);
                }

                mutableData.setValue(p);
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean b, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
            }
        });
    }

    public String getUid()
    {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }

    public abstract Query getQuery(DatabaseReference databaseReference);
}
```

and this is freeboard_include_post_author.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/freeboard_post_author_photo"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000">
        </de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/freeboard_post_author"
            style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            tools:text="someauthor@email.com" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is freeboard_item_post.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/freeboard_post_image"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/freeboard_text_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/freeboard_post_image">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/freeboard_star_layout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/freeboard_post_author_layout"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/freeboard_post_author_layout"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/freeboard_star"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_toggle_star_outline_24" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/freeboard_post_num_stars"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    tools:text="7" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/freeboard_post_text"
                layout="@layout/freeboard_include_post_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/freeboard_post_author_layout"
                android:layout_below="@+id/freeboard_post_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/freeboard_include_post_author"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thank you so much for reading my long codes. I was having a hard time displaying user's image with star button with it. When I click star, the firebase immediately deletes "image" value from the same child.

This is before I click star
[image: This is before I click star]

and this is after I click star button.
[image]

I am 100% sure there is no code that deletes the child or value.. but why does it remove my image address from the child..? I am so curious about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the code that creates instances of `FreeboardPost` in the database.  I'm guessing that you are using `toMap()` because it stores the image URL in a field named `image`, which appears in the database sample you posted.

In your transaction you are using Firebase to serialize/deserialize `FreeboardPost`.  It expects to find the image URL in a field named `imageUrl`, because that is the public field name in your class.  When the node you posted is read, there is no field named `imageUrl` so the created instance of `FreeboardPost` has null for that field value.  When the instance is written, there is no value written for `imageUrl`because it is null, and the previous database value for `image` is lost because `FreeboardPost` has no field with that name.

If you want to use the Firebase capabilities to serialize/deserialize your `FreeboardPost`, you should use them for all database reads and writes.  Using `updateMap()` or `setValue()` with a map to write instances and then a POJO class to read risks naming mismatches.

Comment: I tried setValue() but didn't work. But the thing is that when starClicked function is disabled, imageUrl works completely fine

Comment: Post the code you use to create instances of `FreeboardPost` in the database.